# Wrap content inside box

Tags: android, user-interface

How can I wrap the content inside a box? Just like twitter.

Check how is Twitter and how is mine:

http://img17.imageshack.us/img17/8241/stackoverflow.png

Comment: Try to explain a bit what you want to accomplish. In this case the image isn't that worth many words...

Comment: All the tweets are inside a white box. I`ve tried to do something like that, but when the list is too big and you scroll, only the content inside the box moves, not the whole box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the effect your trying to go far, you're going to have to use a 9patch png as your background image for your ListView and set padding on your ListView to match the size of your border on your 9patch.
The 9patch should look exactly like the background as it shows in the Twitter example.

[You can learn more about 9patches here.](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html)

Comment: I`ve already tried that and other stuffs. The problem is that when the list is too long and you scroll, the content inside the box that moves, not the whole box...

Comment: Edited my answer to reflect this.

Comment: But if I set a padding on my ListView, the scrollbar also receive the padding, and in Twitter the scrollbar has no padding... Check it out: http://img696.imageshack.us/img696/1861/aaaaadj.png

Answer (score 0):

It's an optical illusion.  You really want to create three 9-patches - top item, middle item, bottom item.  Then dynamically set the background drawable for each item based on its position in the list.  Just make sure your borders line up properly between the drawables and you should be fine.